# (bash/Linux) most efficient way to subset rows and columns based on row and column indices in other files

Tags: linux, bash, performance, memory, subset

I have a data file with millions of rows and thousands of columns. I need the data for certain rows and certain columns. I have a text file with the line numbers I need, and another text file with the column headers I need. I have to subset a couple hundred data files like this, so I'm trying to figure out how to do it quickly, without creating huge intermediate files.

I'm not very experienced in bash scripting. My best approach so far has been to use awk to extract the necessary lines to create an intermediate file, and pipe the results to cut so that the output file only contains the necessary columns:

```
COLS=($(zcat big_zipped_file.txt.gz | head -n 1 | tr '\t' '\n' | grep -nf column_headers.txt | sed 's/:.*$//'))

awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} FNR in a' line_numbers.txt <(zcat big_zipped_file.txt.gz) | 
  cut -f 1$(printf ",%s" "${COLS[@]}") >> output_file
```

Is there a way to do this that's faster, and doesn't create large temp files?

Comment: consider reviewing [How to create a minimal, reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then come back and update the question; in particular, sample files containing the row and column header data, an input file with 5-10 rows and columns (should include both rows and columns to keep as well as some to ignore), the (wrong) output generated by your code, and the (correct) expected output

Comment: `csvcut` from the csvkit package is often handy for extracting columns by name.

Comment: markp-fuso: Thank you for your response. The question applies to any large file with rows and columns, so I left out the sample files deliberately, on the grounds that they would be unnecessary clutter. Perhaps I should clarify that I'm already getting the right output. The question is: is there a more efficient way of getting it?

Comment: Are the column and row files common to all data files? To what would the row numbered `1` correspond: the header or the first line of data after the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to scan each file once.

We use `gawk` standard Linux `awk` script.

Reading first 2 files are columns.txt and rows.txt (order not important).

Reading 1 or more data files one after the other, without any temporary files.

#### Input files

##### rows.txt

```
1
7
5
2
```

##### columns.txt

```
col5
col3
col2
```

##### data.txt

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
11   12    13    14   15
21   22    23    24   25
31   32    33    34   35
41   42    43    44   45
51   52    53    54   55
61   62    63    64   65
71   72    73    74   75
```

#### script.awk

```
BEGIN {
    rowsNumbersFileName="rows.txt";
    clumnNamesFileName="columns.txt";
}

ENDFILE { # mark data files when inputFilesCount > 1
    ++inputFilesCount;
 }
 
FILENAME == rowsNumbersFileName { # read rows number
    rowsArr[$0] = ++rowsCount;
}

FILENAME == clumnNamesFileName { # read desired column headers
    columnHeadersArr[$0] = ++columnHeadersCount;
}

inputFilesCount > 1 && FNR == 1 { # caluculate column headers markers
    OFS = "";
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { # scan all header names
        if ($i in columnHeadersArr) { # if current field is in columnHeadersArr
            columnNumbersArr[++columnNumbersCount] = i; # collect field name in columnNumbersArr
            printf ("%s   %s", OFS, $i); # Ouput current field as header
            OFS = ","; 
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    next;
}

inputFilesCount > 1  && (FNR - 1) in rowsArr {
    OFS = "";
     for (currColumnNum in columnNumbersArr) {
        printf ("%s     %s", OFS, $columnNumbersArr[currColumnNum]);
        OFS = ",";
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

#### Output

```
awk -f script.awk rows.txt columns.txt data.txt
   col2,   col3,   col5
     12,     13,     15
     22,     23,     25
     52,     53,     55
     72,     73,     75
```